# Insert tracepoint statements automatically in C++ using liblttng

Tags: c++, function, logging, trace, lttng

I am working with a user-space C++ application and using the Linux trace tool kit, which provides tracepoints (provider, name, etc.).

I want to place in my source code a

> - tracepoint(provider, name, ...)

statement at every function entry and exit point.

Is it possible to *automate* this by some means? It is very cumbersome to place all of these manually.

I want to do this some way other than aspect programming.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `liblttng-ust-cyg-profile.so` helper library to obtain LTTng-UST tracepoints from every function entry and exit.

- Recompile the program with `-g -finstrument-functions`.
- Run it by preloading the helper library:

  - `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/liblttng-ust-cyg-profile.so ./myApp`

This will generate trace events for every instrumented function entry and exit. Note that the tracepoints will only contain the function addresses, not the names. This is a limitation of cyg-profile. To map these back to function names, you can use a utility like `addr2line`.

See the [Function Tracing](http://lttng.org/docs/#doc-liblttng%E2%80%91ust%E2%80%91cyg%E2%80%91profile) part of the documentation for more details.

Depending on the amount of instrumented functions, this may have a non-negligible performance impact. Also, `-finstrument-functions` should technically work with C++ applications, but it can be finicky. I've had it fail compiling with large, non-trivial C++ applications. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: you say that liblttng-ust-cyg-profile.so can be used                                    -  - to obtain tracepoints from every function entry and exit.                                                            I want to be able to insert my tracepoint statements at function entry and exit